# Counting length of string with HTML numbered entities in PHP

Tags: php, html-entities, strlen

I would like to count the length of a string with PHP. The string contains HTML entity numbers, which inflate the number of characters that are counted: a dash is `&#8211;` which is counted as 7 when I only want it to count as 1.

How do I convert the html numbered entities to a form where special characters are only counted with a length of 1?

Example string:

```
Goth-Trad &#8211; &#8216;Cosmos&#8217;
```

The code:

```
$string = html_entity_decode('Goth-Trad &#8211; &#8216;Cosmos&#8217;');
    echo strlen($string);
```

produces '38', when I'm looking for '20'. What is going wrong?

Comment: Even though you have used a `htmlentities` tag, didn't you see *See Also* part of http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation did not provide me with the result I was looking for, which is why I'm posting the question on SO. I would appreciate it if you don't immediately downvote without knowing the background of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$html = 'Goth-Trad &#8211; &#8216;Cosmos&#8217;';
echo strlen(utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')));
```

Comment: Same comment as above unfortunately: this code produces 38, when it should be 20. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @PeterKrejci nice, beat be by a few minutes!

Comment: I see utf8_decode() converts dash and apostrophe into question mark. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

Just decode it and count the decoded one?

```
$string = html_entity_decode("Goth-Trad &#8211; &#8216;Cosmos&#8217;",ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
echo strlen($string);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this exact code fragment still produces 38, when it should be 20. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @Squrler you're right, I just tried it out and the php function cannot decode the entities. The code is right, though. I'll investigate the issue

Comment: @Damien, thanks! Peter below has just updated his answer which produces the results I was looking for. Thanks again for answering!

Comment: @Squrler setting the encoding to UTF-8 looked like solving the problem? I get 26 though, see here http://codepad.org/iizpEyVX

Comment: @Squrler DAmn, I've been too slow :)

Answer (score -1):

Please Try with the following coding function:

```
<?php   

$string='Goth-Trad &#8211; &#8216;Cosmos&#8217;'; 

echo html_entity_text_length($string); // Calling the function 

//html_entity_text_length function start

function html_entity_text_length($string){
    preg_match_all("/&(.*)\;/U", $string, $pat_array);
    $additional=0;
    foreach ($pat_array[0] as $key => $value) {
       $additional += (strlen($value)-1);
    }

    $limit+=$additional;
    return  strlen($string)-$limit;
}

//html_entity_text_length function end

?>
```

Comment: upgrade answer. not clerify

Comment: This is a code dump .. can you turn this into a proper answer? If not, it will likely be removed. Look at other answers to other questions.